# Outlook-Addin: Reply to E-Mail should take sender, who received the message

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

probably you have a good idea how to make this working:
On Outlook, if you have x Accounts, but get the Mail from all account on the same folder, it replies from the current account, not from the E-Mail, which got the E-Mail.
For example:

I have two Accounts: matthias@gmx.ch, mueller@gmx.ch

If someone sends me something to matthias@gmx.ch, but I'm currently under the Account mueller@gmx.ch, it replies as mueller@gmx.ch, not as matthias@gmx.ch.

I'm trying to tinker arround with an Addin, which basically gets the "NewInspector" event, saves the current mailaddress, and tries to check the new MailItem address etc.

But it's really looking ugly and error prone.

So is there a easier solution to make this behavior working, without catching every Inspector? This seems to be a problem many people could run into, isn't it?